# Facebook Graph API-Account suspension

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a .Net application that uses list of names/email addresses and finds there match on Facebook using the graph API. During testing, my list had 900 names...I was checking facebook matches for each name in in a loop...The process completed...After that when I opened my Facebook page...it gave me message that my account has been suspended due to suspicious activities?
What am I doing wrong here? Doesn't facebook allow to search large number requests to their server? And 900 doesn't seem to be a big number either..

Comment: What is it that you are trying to find out? If an email exists for a user on facebook? If so - why? Secondly - 900 requests is not alot - but, 900 sequential requests all comming from the same client very rapidly **is** suspicious...

Comment: I'm trying to search people on facebook by their email address as searching criteria

Answer (score 0):

per the platform policies: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ this may be the a suspected breach of their "Principals" section.

See Policies I.5

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds
>   please contact us by creating confidential bug report with the
>   "threshold policy" tag as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M
>   MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).

Also IV.5

> Facebook messaging (i.e., email sent to an @facebook.com address) is
>   designed for communication between users, and not a channel for
>   applications to communicate directly with users.

Then the biggie, V. Enforcement.  No surprise, it's both automated and also monitored by humans.  So maybe seeing 900+ requests coming from your app.

**What I'd recommend doing:**

Storing what you can client side (in a cache or data store) so you make fewer calls to the API.

Put logging on your API calls so you, the developer, can see exactly what is happening. You might be surprise at what you find there.